# A more elegant way to do: $\int \frac{\sin^2x}{1+\sin^2x} \ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

So I have come across this integral:

$$I=\int \frac{\sin^2x}{1+\sin^2 x}\,\mathrm dx $$

What I did was, split the integral, then used Pythagorean identity and split up the fraction.

$$I=  x - \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} \int \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} - \cos x} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2} + \cos x} \right) \,\mathrm dx $$

Then using the Weiserstrass Substitution ($ t= \tan x/2$), but I only ever use that if its a last resort and in this case I cannot find a more elegant way to solve this integral.

Is there a more elegant/faster way to do this integral (maintaining elementary methods).
I have tried to find a clever way to multiply by 1 but nothing occurs to me at this moment

Thank You.

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

$$\frac{\sin^2x}{1+\sin^2x}=1-\frac1{1+\sin^2x}=1-\frac{\sec^2x}{\sec^2x+\tan^2x}==1-\frac{\sec^2x}{1+2\tan^2x}$$

Put $\tan x=u$

Comment: I see, very well done, thank you.

Comment: @Sy123, my pleasure. Using $\cos2x=1-2\sin^2x,$

$$\int \frac{\sin^2x}{1+\sin^2 x} \ dx=\int\frac{1-\cos2x}{3-\cos2x}\ dx$$ then we can use Weiserstrass Substitution $t=\tan x,$ to reach at the same destination in a longer way

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int \frac{\operatorname{sin}^2x}{1+\operatorname{sin}^2x}dx=\int \left ( 1-\frac{1}{\operatorname{sin}^2x+1} \right )dx=\int dx-\operatorname{sin}\frac{dx}{1+\operatorname{sin}^2x}$$
$$I_1=\int \frac{dx}{\operatorname{sin}^2x+1}=\int -\left ( -\frac{1}{\operatorname{cot}^2+2} \right )\operatorname{csc}^2xdx=\begin{vmatrix}
t=\operatorname{cot}x\\ 
dx=-\frac{1}{\operatorname{csc}^2x}dt
\end{vmatrix}=-\int \frac{dt}{t^2+2}=$$
$$=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\operatorname{arctan\left ( \frac{t}{\sqrt{2}} \right )}+C$$
$$I=x-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\operatorname{arctan}\left ( \sqrt{2}\operatorname{tan}x \right )+C$$